# Which is better to an annoying sibling: "deja de copiarme" or "para de copiarme"?

Tags: vocabulario

Are both correct? What's the difference in connotation?

Comment: Are you trying to say: Stop imitating me?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (5yo echoes: "yes, exactly!")

Comment: That made me laugh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in denotative or connotative meaning between:

"Deja de copiarme, little brother/sister"

and

"Para de copiarme, little brother/sister".

Both are correct and natural.

The only slight difference might be one of register. The verb "parar" in verb phrases like "parar de + infinitive" is a bit more informal than the neutral "dejar de + infinitive".

Comment: @今夜九 You are right. I read "S" instead of "5".